# how to exclude weekend from month using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, date, calendar

Hi want to exclude weekend from month please help me.
But this is not Exclude weekend from month how to Exclude Weekend.

```
 <%     
    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();                                               int  day = cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
    int days=day-1;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date1 = df.parse("1/02/2014");
    Date date2 = new Date();    
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    int numberOfDays = 0;
    while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
        if ((Calendar.SATURDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))&&(Calendar.SUNDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) 
        {
            numberOfDays++;
          session.setAttribute("numberOfDays",numberOfDays);
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }else {
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }

    }           

    %>
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare with `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` instead of `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`

So your condition becomes:

```
if ((Calendar.SATURDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                    && (Calendar.SUNDAY != cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JANUARY , 24 ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Define a collection of the day-of-week values that we care about, that we want to include in our results. An `EnumSet` is a highly-optimized implementation of `Set` for collecting enum objects. So we can collect `DayOfWeek` objects to define your desired days, weekdays without Saturday & Sunday.

```
Set < DayOfWeek > weekDays = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ;  // Not Saturday-Sunday.
```

Loop your days, increment to the following day, and test the day-of-week of each date.

```
List < LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>() ;

LocalDate target = ld ;
while( target.isBefore( today ) ) {
    DayOfWeek dow = target.getDayOfWeek() ;  // Determine the day-of-week of this date.
    if( weekDays.contains( dow ) {
        dates.add( target ) ;
    }
    target = target.plusDays( 1 ) ; // Setup for the next loop. Increment for next day.
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).